# Command prompt to search for Task Name

Tags: command-line

how can we find / detect on what ever application is running and can be seen from the Windows Task Manager ?
Example, im opening 2 firefox, so under the Task Manager > Process, it will be 2 firefox.exe but i want to know if the firefox is on Gmail page ? Under the Windows Task Manager > Applications tab, it will show the Task (with the naming) and Status....
Is it possible to use command prompt to list / find if there is any application running with Task name like '%gmail%' ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple of apps you can use with what your asking. They require some knowledge so search around to know all the options but those are:

1. tasklist
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx
2. get-process (in PS)
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6
3. WMIC
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Those may be a good start but with what you're asking, this link may be able to help you but you have to know about c#:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c5b3365f-2e13-4f90-9fe5-0d5eae14da27/get-process-id-from-window-title?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.